# Design for nonstandard navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on few views in an app that doesn't fit to any of standard Apple ViewControllers and I'm looking for a best solution for my problem.

Here is a quick mockup how it looks like:

http://pl.tinypic.com/r/2va1kbc/5

I have a main ViewController which is build of out 2 parts:
1. Top part which is always visible containing some logo
2. Content part which is changing - every content is a class (extending UIViewController)

Now tricky part is I want to do some animations in between of content changes - when user clicks a button on first one, top part slides down - pushing current viewController down, covers full screen and than slides up with a new viewController content.

So question is how to build it so it's easy to use and extend later (like UINavigationController).

I created a main view as UIViewController and added topView using:

```
 LogoUIViewController *logoViewController = [[LogoUIViewController alloc] init];
 [self.view addSubview:logoViewController.view];

 LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
 loginViewController.delegate = self;
 [self.view addSubview:loginViewController.view];
```

I'm using delegate to initialize a transition on main view controller, because I couldn't find a better way of doing it.

But with that solution I stucked because of those problems:
1. How to make content view controller to only use part of screen (change it size) ?
2. How to animate those 2 views so it will look like top layer is pushing away content ?
3. How to exchange views in an easy way (like UINavigationController popViewController way) and initialize animation automatically between them.

I know those are 3 problems, but I think it can be solved with better way of constructing the main view controller. Does anyone have experience with custom navigation systems like that ?

Answer (score 1):

A `UIPageViewController` could be helpful.  It would contain your content view controllers.  The root vc that contains the page view controller can also be made it's delegate.

When you want to initiate a content view change, the root vc can do any animation it likes with it's page vc's view (like slide it down to reveal a larger header view).  When the page transition is complete, as the delegate, the root vc can get notified with

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
```

and then animate the restoration of it's view.  Pretty simple, I think, and saves you a fair amount of effort on the container vc pattern.  Xcode's default Paged App template is a really good starting point.